# JButton Array with actionListener...trouble printing out result

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

Basically I've made a array for each letter of the alphabet and then added it to a array of JButtons. That works fine however I've now attempted to add on a action listener which I managed to succesfully get working.

BUT, it works as I have 26 if statements to check if each button is pressed hence why I've tried adding a for loop.

Now whenether I press the button it prints out a load of garbage regarding the JbUTTON properties. Where could I be going wrong?

```
String[] letters = { "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M" };
    layout.add(scrollBar);
     for (int i=0; i < 26; i++)
     {

        if (i==25)
        {
            layout.add(spacebar);
            spacebar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(310,50));
            spacebar.setBackground(Color.black);
            spacebar.setForeground(Color.white);
            spacebar.addActionListener(new action());
        }

         AlphaButton[i] = new JButton(letters[i]);
         AlphaButton[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
         AlphaButton[i].setBackground(Color.black);
         AlphaButton[i].setForeground(Color.white);
         layout.add(AlphaButton[i]);
         AlphaButton[i].addActionListener(new action());
     }
    class action implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String V = screenArea.getText();

                for (int i=0; i < 26; i++)
                {
                    if( e.getSource() == AlphaButton[i] )
                    {
                        screenArea.setText(V + AlphaButton[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to return the letter that was pressed:

```
screenArea.setText(V + AlphaButton[i].getText);
```

Comment: +1 now I think about it, this seems like the more appropriate simplest answer OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `AlphaButton` `toString` method

```
// your class
public class AlphaButton {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "This is an AlphaButton";  // or whatever output you want it to say
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   String V = screenArea.getText();
   screenArea.setText(V + e.getActionCommand());
}
```